# Using Intel MKL in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intel-mkl

After installing Intel MKL on my Windows 7 64-bit pc, I was under the impression that running the provided script `mklvars.bat -arch` available in `"install_dir"\mkl\bin` would make it possible to include mkl.h in my Visual Studio 2010 project. Instead I get an error that VS cannot find the header file, anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the [Intel MKL configuring for Microsoft VS Manual](http://download-software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/184496/intel-mkl-configuring-in-microsoft-visual-studio.pdf) to get a simple project to see the headers.

I created a new project as instructed there, copy-pasted an MKL example into a new file, and then added the include path - for me C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\mkl\include - using the VS menu Project->Properties->C++->General->Additional Include Directories.